# Regex Match problems

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string

> `<a href="/makeuppro/video?st.cmd=altGroupVideoAll&amp;st.groupId=oqxdtikenuenvnwuj0rxiwhgvyuvhjhzjrd&amp;st.directLink=on&amp;st.referenceName=makeuppro&amp;st._aid=NavMenu_AltGroup_Video"`

I need to get the groupID `oqxdtikenuenvnwuj0rxiwhgvyuvhjhzjrd`.

I tried

```
string groupId = Regex.Match(content, @"altGroupVideoAll&amp;st.groupId=(?<id>[^""]+)&amp").Groups["id"].Value;
```

But the result was:

```
oizrximcmbsyyvjxacd0rpkkmgxwuvhinnuvczz&amp;st.directLink=on&amp;st.referenceName=makeuppro
```

Why, and what is the correct regex?

Comment: I think a more robust approach would be to get the entire URL, then parse it with something like `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use reluctant quantifier to stop at the first `&amp`: -

```
@"altGroupVideoAll&amp;st.groupId=(?<id>[^""]+?)&amp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
groupId=(?<id>[^&]+)
```

I suspect the id won't contain & character. Your original regex is greedy and tries to match the longest string possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hy @user1895750 and @Jared Harley,

You made confuse with Lazy and Greedy Expression, see the code below.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Example for how to extract the group Id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string ExtractNumber(string xml)
    {
        // Extracted number.
        string groupId = string.Empty;

        // Input text
        xml = @"<a href=""/makeuppro/video?st.cmd=altGroupVideoAll&amp;st.groupId=oqxdtikenuenvnwuj0rxiwhgvyuvhjhzjrd&amp;st.directLink=on&amp;st.referenceName=makeuppro&amp;st._aid=NavMenu_AltGroup_Video""";

        // Here is the key, you have to use "?" after "(?<id>[^\"\"]+"
        // This is called "Lazy expression", and it is different from the "Greedy expression".
        // Lazy expression uses the "?", like ".*?\r". So it will match the expression until they find the first carriage return (\r).
        // If you use ".*\r" (Greedy Expression), it will match until they find the last carriage return of the input. Thats why you matched ("&amp;st.directLink=on&amp;st.referenceName=makeuppro"), because the last "&amp" is after "makeuppro" .
        // Here the correct pattern.
        var pattern = "groupId=(?<id>[^\"\"]+?)&amp";

        // Match the desired part of the input.
        var match = Regex.Match(xml, pattern);

        // Verify the match sucess.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, use the group value to isolate desired value.
            groupId = match.Groups["id"].Value;
        }

        return groupId;
    }
```

I hope it helps you!

Sincerely,